# Xamarin bind to another element from within a listview itemtemplate

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a list view, with an itemtemplate, datatemplate, viewcell etc.  In there I have a bunch of controls binding to the item properties.  That all works great, but I do not seem to be able to reference another element on the same page within it, for example,

```
{Binding Path=MyProperty, Source={Reference AnotherElement}}
```

Even though I have another element on the same page called 'AnotherElement' that exposes 'MyProperty' and this exact binding works in other areas on the same page, I cannot get any bindings to refer to another element from within the listview itemtemplate.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in a listview item template the Xamarin Forms ListView needs a binding context to map the binding with by that i mean it needs the reference of the Source of its binding context you can provide that using the ListViews `x:Name` property

Give your list view a name:

```
  <ListView x:Name="myList"...>
```

Then use its binding context as Source

```
Path=BindingContext.MyProperty, Source={x:Reference myList}}"/>
```